# ¿Cómo valido un campo en un script de Awk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy intentando ejecutar un script de la forma siguiente:

```
./test_for.awk -v company="Crooks Inc" test_results.csv
```

El script tiene que devolver todos esos registros que tengan por `company` "Crooks Inc" sino tiene que devolver "Sorry, <nombre de la compañia> not found". He hecho lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
# Le paso el parámetro company a la variable empresa
BEGIN{empresa=company}
# Si el campo 3, correspondiente a company es igual al nombre pasado, imprimimos la línea.
{if ($3==empresa) print f=$0}}
# Si el campo 3, no se corresponde al campo company, imprimimos Sorry, <nombrecompañia> not found"
END{if($3!=empresa) {print "Sorry, $empresa not found"}}
```

Sin embargo siempre me muestra "Sorry, $empresa not found".

El dataset con el que estoy trabajando es:

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost
1,Audrey,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,11897.6
2,Audrey,Crooks Inc, Ranique, 15/07/2018, Eavesdropping, 08/17/2020,normal,2567
3, Chris, Johnston and Sons, Travis, 11/11/2018, Phising, 23/09/2020,none,6393
```

Comment: Fíjate que el fichero que le pasas es CSV, pero no defines el separador de campos como ",", por lo que Awk usa el espacio por defecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás validando campos separados por comas, pero no se lo dices. Por tanto, el primer paso sería indicarlo con `FS=","`:

```
BEGIN{empresa=company; FS=","}
```

Después quieres validar si el campo coincide o no. Ahí te sobra una llave de cierre, debería ser apenas esto:

```
{if ($3==empresa) print f=$0}
```

Finalmente, la validación podría ser comparando con `f` en lugar de con `$3`, pues de lo contrario estás validando solamente contra la última línea. Además, en tu script usas `$empresa`, pero no es así como se llaman las variables en Awk. Por el contrario, puedes usar por ejemplo `printf` y allí mencionar las variables normalmente:

```
END{if(!f ) {printf "Sorry, empresa '%s' not found\n", empresa}}
```

Todo junto, puedes decir:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{empresa=company; FS=","}

{if ($3==empresa) print f=$0}

END{if(!f ) {printf "Sorry, empresa '%s' not found\n", empresa}}
```

En cualquier caso, esto en apenas una línea ya lo tienes, no hace falta un script:

```
awk -v company="Crooks Inc" -F, '$3 == company {print; seen=1} END {if (!seen) print "no"}' fichero
```

Comment: Gràcies! Gracias